# What is the syntax for setting 404 fast paths on all Drupal pages in D7 > 7.9

Tags: performance

D7.9 introduced 404 fast paths which don't fully bootstrap drupal on 404's for certain file types if it's enabled, thus saving some bandwidth / computation. More info is available here: http://drupal.org/node/1296384

By default this excludes only certain file types such as .jpg, .txt., etc., looks like this:

```
$conf['404_fast_paths_exclude'] = '/\/(?:styles)\//';
$conf['404_fast_paths'] = '/\.(?:txt|png|gif|jpeg|css|js|ico|swf|flv|cgi|bat|pl|dll|exe|asp)$/i';
```

I want to use this for all paths. Are there any repercussions to that?

I tried changing it to

```
$conf['404_fast_paths'] = '/*$/i';
```

However, this returns a warning:

> Warning: preg_match() Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in drupal_fast_404() (line 2484 of /cms/main/includes/bootstrap.inc).

So what should the syntax look like up there to both work and not generate a warning?

Alternatively, if there isn't a solution to this specific question, is there a way I can speed up 404's for all Drupal pages, would it better to use the Fast 404 contributed module for instance?

Answer (score 5):

You used `"/*$/i"` as regular expression, but there is nothing before the asterisk; in other words, you are not saying what can be repeated zero or more times.
Valid regular expressions expressions such as `"/.*/i"`, `"/[a-zA-Z]*/i"`, `"/(foo|bar)*/i"`.

[drupal_fast_404()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_fast_404/7) is called by [drupal_deliver_html_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7) when the result of [menu_execute_active_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/7) is `MENU_NOT_FOUND`, which means Drupal is asked to look for a path without any menu callback associated.
`drupal_fast_404()` first checks that `$_GET['q']` doesn't match the regular expression contained in the "404_fast_paths_exclude" Drupal variable; if it doesn't match that regular expression, then it checks `$_GET['q']` matches the regular expression contained in the "404_fast_paths" Drupal variable. The default value for that variable is `'/\.(?:txt|png|gif|jpe?g|css|js|ico|swf|flv|cgi|bat|pl|dll|exe|asp)$/i'` which means the fast 404 page is returned when the request is for a file with the following extensions:

- .txt
- .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg
- .css, .js
- .ico, .swf, .flv
- .cgi, .bat, .pl, .dll, .exe, .asp

If you want the fast 404 pages be used in any case, I would not touch the value of the "404_fast_paths_exclude" Drupal variable, and change the content of the "404_fast_paths" Drupal variable to `'/.*/i'`, which would match any path that causes a 404 error, excluding the ones containing "styles."

Comment: Upvoted you, although it should be noted that this doesn't work in the context of Drupal and what I am trying to accomplish, which is why it *is* a Drupal question. If one uses this syntax and drupal_fast_404() called in settings.php it will return all pages as 404 Not Found. However, commenting out the drupal_fast_404() call there along with using this syntax does work (something I figured out after asking the question).

Answer (score 2):

To exclude additional paths, this seems to work:

```
$conf['404_fast_paths_exclude'] = '/\/(?:styles)\/|robots\.txt|(?:another-dir)\//';
```

where 'another-dir' can be the child of a longer path (as is styles).