# Fast 404 module and Drupal core

Tags: performance

I can see that Fast 404 module has been added to drupal core since 7.9 version.
So in order to use it on my drupal site(without installing Fast 404 module),is there I need to do in the settings.php module?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the sites/default directory. Open up to the setting.php file. Around line 500 uncomment this `drupal_fast_404();` by removing `#`

[Source](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1AgnurTWsWdMAFjfFmSU7mk2zfJu8jG_KmVdZ7-o6Pok/edit#slide=id.g385c64257_0178)

Comment: Τhanks you a lot!

Comment: This answer does not seem to apply to Drupal 8. [This one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22498/what-is-the-syntax-for-setting-404-fast-paths-on-all-drupal-pages-in-d7-7-9) worked for me.